# Facebook Feed Dialog - setting the Privacy dropdown

Tags: facebook

When using the Facebook's Feed Dialog, [example](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20%20%20app_id=123050457758183&%20%20%20link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&%20%20%20picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&%20%20%20name=Facebook%20Dialogs&%20%20%20caption=Reference%20Documentation&%20%20%20description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&%20%20%20message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&%20%20%20redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Is it possible to set the privacy dropdown (the one left of the Share button) to default to Public? And how?

(Note: it is OK if the user then changes the dropdown manually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:  `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{App_Id}/auth` and change the default setting for activity.  Supposedly this works for both activity as well as feed posts.  Never tried it, but it seems to be the way.

Also the user will have an option to change it during authentication (IIRC) as well as after the fact they can change the settings of the application via http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications